# Get the index position of an li with a specific class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get jquery to return the index position of the top level li with a class of .open. EG:

```
<ul>
  <li class="open">something
     <ul>
        <li>ignore this</li>
        <li>ignore this</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>something</li>
  <li class="open">something</li>
</ul>
```

So in the case of the above, I want it to ignore anything below the second ul. And return the index position of the top level (IE. ul li siblings only) with the class of .open.

So the above would return:
0 and 2

I've tried this:

```
console.log($('ul:first li.open').index());
```

But this returns odd results. I've also tried this:

```
$('ul:first li.open').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).index());
}
```

But again this doesn't return the expected results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass string selector to `index()` method:

```
 console.log($(this).index('.open'));
```

This will return 0 and 1.

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eH9wT/)

Comment: This is odd. I tried this and it returned 0 and 1. http://jsfiddle.net/eH9wT/1/  I see what it's doing. It is correct because there are only 2 elements with li.open. But I'm trying to get the index position within the ul li that have the class .open..... if you see what I mean.

Comment: @user1001421 No, i don't understand what you mean

Comment: Not really. I'm after the position relevant to the ul li siblings. IE. 0 and 2.

Comment: But then: `$(this).index()` as you were already using it http://jsfiddle.net/eH9wT/2/ If not i'm sorry but really i don't see what you are looking for here??? "But I'm trying to get the index position within the ul li that have the class .open....." In your posted code, none element is like this

Comment: OMG it worked now. I must have been caching something. I kept getting 0 and 1 :)  Big thanks. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Were you looking for something like this? The '>' will assure only immediate children are selected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul:first > li.open').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).index());
    });
});
```